# adding values to the array without initialization the length

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

When I can add values to the array , Exception occurs.
In C# , can i set the values without initializing the array length.

```
int[] test;
test[0] = 10;
```

Comment: An array is a) a reference type b) a fixed-length data-structure. You might want this sugar `int[] test = { 10 };` or `var test = new[] { 10 };`, but otherwise, what you ask for is impossible. Perhaps you want a growable collection such as `List<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only that way

```
int[] a = {10};
```

But the length of the array will be 1 after that.

Answer (score 11):

No, if you want a data structure that dynamically grows as you `Add` items, you will need to use something like `List<T>`. Arrays are fixed in size.

When you have

```
int[] test;
```

you haven't instantiated an array, you've merely declared that `test` is a variable of type `int[]`. You need to also instantiate a new array via

```
int[] test = new int[size];
```

As long as `size` is positive then you can safely say

```
int[0] = 10;
```

In fact, you can say

```
int[index] = 10
```

as long as `0 <= index < size`.

Additionally, you can also declare, instantiate and initialize a new array in one statement via

```
int[] test = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Note that here you do not have to specify the size.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with an array, *per se*, but you can use a List.

```
        List<int> test = new List<int>();
        test.Add(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<int> t = new List<int>()` and use `t.Add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
string[] words;
words = new List<string>() { "hello","hi" }.ToArray()
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.